# How to get results in sorted order when I use facet limit in solr?

Tags: solr, faceted-search, solr-query-syntax

Usually a solr query with facetting option returns the results in sorted order based on the facet count. When I set the facet limit to -1 the results were not returned in sorted order; this means I have to do the sorting manually in the server side.

Should I need to append anything more in the solr query to get it in a sorted order?

Comment: Reason for downvoting ?

Answer (score 3):

please try **facet.sort=count**

The default facet order is base on the count, descending order, but it will return the index order rather than count desc order if facet.limit is less than 0

Details can be read from [Solr Wiki](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SimpleFacetParameters#facet.sort)

Comment: i tried that but it is not working. Still solr returns the result in Unordered fashion.

Comment: Would you mind to share the solr version, field definition, and the solr URL/parameters?